# How to tell Jquery not to remove all content when using the load function?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery function loading a php file which will output some data into a div.
The code:

```
function add(){
    $("#div").load("add.php");
}
```

Now the problem is, I need to be able to use the function several times without my content in `#div` being overwritten. So now each time I use the function the text inside the div is deleted and the new content is inserted.

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add () {
    $( div ).append( $( '<div>' ).load( 'add.php' ) );
}
```

where `div` is a reference to your DIV element. (You want to have a reference of course, instead of querying for the DIV on each invokation of `add()`.)

---

**Update:**

So, the data returned from the server is a `'<li>...</li>'` string, which means that you want to append it directly to the UL element:

```
$.get( 'addday.php', function ( data ) {
    $( ul ).append( data );
});
```

Comment: Btw how would I remove it again?
Just using $( div ).remove( $( '<div>' ).load( 'delete.php' ) );
doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @phpheini This `$( div ).children( 'div' ).remove();` removes all the DIV's that are inside your `div` element.

Comment: Now I got a really weird problem. I created divs for every li element in order to be able to delete the li elements. So now with $("#div").remove( $( "#" + id + "" )... I am removing the div. This works perfectly fine. Now when adding a new element its creating something like <div id=23><li>something</li></div> I am using Jquery to be able to drag and drop the <li>s to sort them. Now when I take a <li> and put it below the <div id=23><li>something</li></div> it puts it INSIDE the div. And so if I delete div with id 23, the second <li> will also be deleted.

Comment: @phpheini Your HTML structure is not valid. You cannot have LI elements as children of DIV elements. LI elements must be children of an UL element. When you define an invalid HTML structure, the browsers change that structure in order to make it valid, hence the weird behavior that you described.

Comment: So I cant even have a structure like <ul><div><li></li></div></ul>? The <li> has to be directly after the <ul>?

Comment: @phpheini Yes. Consider not having those DIV's at all since LI's are container elements themselves. You don't need two container elements in a row...

Comment: but then how could I remove a li element completeley from a ul element? Say each <li> has its own id, then this: $( ul ).children( 'li-id' ).remove(); would only remove then content inside the <li> wouldnt it?

Comment: @phpheini No, it removes the Li element. `$( elem ).remove()` removes the `elem` element, not just its contents.

Comment: Well then it will be complicated: When adding a new li element I need to tell him what item to append to. But: $("#id-of-ul").append( $( '<li>' ).load( 'addday.php' ) ); will not work because the <li> element needs to be outputted by the php file. What could I use then as append element?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use the function to add the content to different `</div>` You can pass the function the target instead of using a static selector like this:

```
// Add Function //
function add($target){
    $target.load('add.php');
}

// Call Function and Pass jQuery Object of Target //
add($('#firstDiv'));
add($('#someOtherDiv'));
```

If you plan to use the function to add to the same div you can modify the above function like this:

```
function add($target){    
    $target.append($('<span>').load('add.php'));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

using `$.ajax()` you can get the response and append it to your div:

```
$.ajax({
    url:     'add.php',
    type:    'GET',
    success: function(response) {
                var html = $("#div").html();
                $("#div").html(html + response);
                // or jQuery(response).wrap('<p />').appendTo('#div');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("add.php", function (data) {
    $("#div").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `.get()` function with a specific success handler instead:

```
$.get('add.php', function(data) {
  $('#div').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.get('add.php', function(data) {
    $('#div').append(data);
});
```